# Camunda - Disable demo user getting created every startup?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-18.04, camunda, systemctl

I have deployed **Camunda 7.15.0** in a **Ubuntu 18.04 EC2** machine (downloaded the .zip, extracted it, and then ran the .sh file). For the initial login to Camunda dashboard, I used the 'demo' user and its credentials. As 'demo' user has admin privileges and its credentials are publicly available, I created another user with my own credentials and deleted the 'demo' user. Note that I have added Camunda.sh as a Systemctl service, so that whenever the server reboots, the Camunda service gets started too.

However, when I **restarted the Camunda EC2 server** (for my own reasons), while Camunda started without any issue, I can see that **'demo' user has been created again**. Is there a way to disable this from happening (via Dashboard or by modifying Camunda files in the EC2)?

Comment: If this solves the issue, please accept the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A) If you are using the **Tomcat distribution**, check if your distribution contains the example web application **camunda-invoice** in the folder `\camunda-bpm-.....\server\apache-tomcat-9.....\webapps`

This example project contains *org.camunda.bpm.example.invoice.DemoDataGenerator*, which creates the user here:
https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/7c5bf37307d3eeac3aee5724b6e4669a9992eaba/examples/invoice/src/main/java/org/camunda/bpm/example/invoice/DemoDataGenerator.java#L78

You can just **delete the folder camunda-invoice** completely if you dont want the example.

If you want to consume a pre-built distribution, then I would recommend to also have a look at the newer RUN distribution:
https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/user-guide/camunda-bpm-run/
which is available as the standard download on the CAMUNDA website:
https://camunda.com/download/

B) If you are using the **RUN distribution** then remove the admin-user section:

```
camunda.bpm:
  #admin-user:
  #id: demo
  #password: demo
  run:
# https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/camunda-bpm-run/#cross-origin-resource-sharing
    cors:
      enabled: true
      allowed-origins: "*"
```

from the configuration file **camunda-bpm-run-7.....\configuration\default.yml**,  lines 5-8.

If you are preparing for production usage you may also want to consider using the production.yml config file instead.
Please see related documentation covering various configuration options here:  https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/camunda-bpm-run/

Comment: Hi, I searched for this directory, but cannot find anything named camunda-bpm-ee-tomcat-7.

Comment: The path name can differ based on the distribution you are using. There will be no -ee in the path if you are using community edition. Is there surely no camunda-invoice subfolder in what you have unzipped? Which distribution did you download?

Comment: No camunda-invoice subfolder.    I downloaded this file and extracted it. https://downloads.camunda.cloud/release/camunda-bpm/run/7.15/camunda-bpm-run-7.15.0.zip

Comment: please see section B) added to the answer

Comment: I commented those lines, but now the service fails to start.

Comment: You probably remove camunda.bpm: completely, but this is also the root of run: and everything under it. I update the example to show how to comment out only the admin user creation.

Comment: Thanks, uncommenting that line did the trick. However, you have mentioned production.yml file in your answer. It does not have any demo user. What's that about?

Comment: See https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.15/user-guide/camunda-bpm-run/  : " The production.yml configuration is intended to provide the recommended properties according to the Security Instructions. When using Camunda Platform Run in a production environment, make sure to base your custom configuration on this one and carefully read through the security instructions. By default, Run launches with the default.yml configuration. To enable the production.yml configuration, execute the start script, through a command-line interface, with the --production property."